# ASP.NET Login control, how to query user-specific data

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership, asp.net-3.5

I have installed a Login control in ASP.NET/C# in login.aspx and after the user has logged in, it takes him to the member.aspx page. All works perfectly fine but what should I do if I want to query a database for some user-specific data? How would I do that?

ASPNETDB.MDF is the database, I have created another table with some additional fields for the user.

So after the member.aspx has been loaded I put a LoginName control so extract the user's name but how can I use this to query the database for some info?

I tried calling the database with owner user/pwd but it doesn't work. It says "Login failed for ". Is there any other way of doing that?

Basically I want to show data to the user in a gridview so the user can edit it.

Comment: Need more information on what data you've stored that you want to retrieve. By user specific data, do you mean data specific to the system user, or data specified by you, the developer?

Comment: I mean like a table "info" is created for all users with properties such as "name", "age", "grades" and so forth so when the user logs in with a Login control, I want to display data specific to that user so he can edit/modify them.

I created that table in a ASPNETDB.MDF database which is automatically created when building Login control and related it to the aspnet_Users table but I don't know how to pull this off. How do I get user-specific data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using the ASP.NET login system, you could take a look at the [Profile system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use profiles but if you have more spefic requirement then you can inherit the login control and create your controls.

Comment: Profile system is enough for what I'm doing right now but where can I learn more about inheriting the login control and creating my own controls? I would appreciate a source with examples.